# How to recreate a race condition in JAVA?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am learning the java multithread and tried to create a race condition in JAVA. And this is my code.

```
package com.company;

public class Account  {
    private double balance = 100;

    public  double getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    public void setBalance(double balance) {
        this.balance = balance;
    }
    public   boolean withdraw(double amount,String name){

        if(this.getBalance()>amount){
            this.setBalance(this.getBalance() - amount);
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " withdraw " + amount);
            System.out.println("Hello,  " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " You current balance is " + this.getBalance());

            return true;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Sorry, " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + ". Your current balance is " + this.getBalance() + " and you  cannot withdraw " + amount);
            //System.out.println("Welcome,  " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " You current balance is " + this.getBalance());

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

and the main class

```
package com.company;
public class Main implements Runnable {
    Account account = new Account();
    public static void main(String[] args){
            Main main = new Main();
            for(int i= 0; i< 2; i++) {
                Thread c1 = new Thread(main, "customer" + i);
                c1.start();
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "'s balance is " + account.getBalance());
        account.withdraw(60, Thread.currentThread().getName());
        //
    }
}
```

Supposingly, this should produce a racing condition, two customers withdraw 60 dollars at the same time, and the getBalance() should show me that each custom CAN withdraw 60 dollars and the balance is 40 dollars for each customer. But I can NEVER reproduce this. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You could try to make threads stop at "critical places" with breakpoints. Or insert Thread#sleep to make them slow down between lines.

Comment: Also, without any `volatile` or `synchronized`, your class is not guaranteed to properly publish its state between multiple threads.

Comment: Do you see anything output? What do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily easy to reproduce a race condition. It often depends on the timing of the thread scheduler.

You can influence it just a bit by making one of your threads sleep

```
if (this.getBalance() > amount) {
    if (Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("customer0"))
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1); // simulates a quicker thread context switch
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    this.setBalance(this.getBalance() - amount);
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " withdraw " + amount);
    System.out.println("Hello,  " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " You current balance is " + this.getBalance());

    return true;
}
```

Note that even this is not a guarantee. It worked on my system, it might not work on yours. That's why race conditions are annoying. They are hard to reproduce consistently.